# Update data in parent element whenever it updates in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Ok so let's say I have 2 components in vue, Parent.vue and Child.vue.
In Child.vue I have this

```
data () {
  return {
    childData
  }
},
```

In Parent.vue I get the data from child using this

```
data(){
return{
  dataFromChild : child.data().childData,
 }
},
```

Everything good here but I have one problem, childData will get updated based on what the user does, how do I make so that dataFromChild updates whenever childData updates? I would prefer not to use event bus or vuex as it is overkill for my case.

Comment: Emit the data via events:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript (and thus Vue.js) is event-driven. Are you sure using events are overkill for your case?

In an essence, you want to update the parent data, when the child data change. This change is an event. "Something" is happening, so your Parent can react to it.

I assume that you are setting the ref on the child component. I'd like to bring your attention to this section of the guide:

*$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive.*

I recommend you to use Vue.js event system:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html